# NHibernate <Join/> with filters

Tags: .net, nhibernate, join, filter

I was hoping there would be a simple answer to this one....

I have a global filter designed to avoid soft deletes in the database, this works fine in the rest of my system. However we are using a legacy database with an existing "**UserBase**" table, any new properties we required we added to a "**User**" table and mapped our User class to retrieve data from 2 tables using the "join" mapping - this way we are not altering the existing "**UserBase**" table.

Again this works fine, until we try to apply the soft delete filter to the class - as the generated SQL applies the filter to the "**BaseUser**" table where there is no matching column.

```
 <class name="User" table="UserBase">
    <id name="Id" column="userid" type="Int32" unsaved-value="-1">
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence"></param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Email" column="UserEmail" type="String" length="100" />
    .........
    .........
    <join table="User" optional="false">
     <key column="UserID"  />
     <property name="TimeZone" column="timezone" type="Int32" />
     .........
     .........
     <property name="IsDeleted" column="IsDeleted" type="Boolean" />
    </join>

    <filter name="AvoidLogicalDeleted" condition="IsDeleted = 0" />
 </class>
```

Is there any way that I can get the filter to apply to the "joined" table, rather than the class table?

I have also tried to specify a "subselect" in the "join" mapping with a where clause ignoring soft deletes, but it appears to be ignored!?

A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I have an answer so much as a work around.  Instead of mapping the **User** class to the *UserBase* table and then joined to the *User* table, what about using a view?  Perhaps you can create a view in the database called *UserView* which has the *UserBase* and *User* tables joined and then map the **User** class to that view.  NHibernate should then treat the *IsDeleted* column like any other column and the filter should work.

Another option that occurred to me is to swap the mapping of the **User** class from *UserBase* to *User*.  The *IsDeleted* column will then no longer be in the joined table but in the main table connected to **User**.  Then, the fact that the filter isn't working on a joined table won't matter.